# Prove if $|z|=|w|=1$, and $1+zw \neq 0$, then $ {{z+w} \over {1+zw}} $ is a real number

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|z|=|w|=1$, and $1+zw \neq 0$, then $ {{z+w} \over {1+zw}} \in \Bbb R $

i found one link that had a similar problem. 
[Prove if $|z| < 1$ and $ |w| < 1$, then $|1-zw^*| \neq 0$ and $| {{z-w} \over {1-zw^*}}| < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343982/prove-if-z-1-and-w-1-then-1-zw-neq-0-and-z-w-over-1)

Comment: have you consciously changed to $z+w$ from $z-w?$

Comment: yeah , my buddy send me the wrong signal...

Comment: This change means nothing; it replaces $w$ with $-w$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Let $z=\cos A+i\sin A, w=\cos B+i\sin B$

$\implies z\cdot w=\cos(A+B)+i\sin(A+B)$

Using $\cos C-\cos D=-2\sin\frac{C-D}2\sin\frac{C+D}2$

and  $\sin C-\sin D=2\sin\frac{C-D}2\cos\frac{C+D}2$

$$\frac{z-w}{1-zw}=\frac{\cos A-\cos B+i(\sin A-\sin B)}{1-\{\cos(A+B)+i\sin(A+B)\}}$$

$$=\frac{-2\sin\frac{A-B}2\sin\frac{A+B}2+i2\sin\frac{A-B}2\cos\frac{A+B}2}{2\sin^2\frac{A+B}2-i2\sin\frac{A+B}2\cos\frac{A+B}2}$$

$$=\frac{2i\sin\frac{A-B}2\left(i\sin\frac{A+B}2+\cos\frac{A+B}2\right)}{-2i\sin\frac{A+B}2\left(i\sin\frac{A+B}2+\cos\frac{A+B}2\right)}$$

$$=\frac{\sin\frac{A-B}2}{-\sin\frac{A+B}2}$$

**EDIT**:  The changed question can be addressed in the same way using

$\cos C+\cos D=2\cos\frac{C-D}2\cos\frac{C+D}2$

and  $\sin C+\sin D=2\sin\frac{C+D}2\cos\frac{C-D}2$

$$\frac{z+w}{1+zw}=\frac{\cos A+\cos B+i(\sin A+\sin B)}{1+\{\cos(A+B)+i\sin(A+B)\}}$$

$$=\frac{2\cos\frac{A+B}2\cos\frac{A-B}2+i2\sin\frac{A+B}2\cos\frac{A-B}2}{2\cos^2\frac{A+B}2+i2\sin\frac{A+B}2\cos\frac{A+B}2}$$

$$=\frac{2\cos\frac{A-B}2\left(\cos\frac{A+B}2+i\sin\frac{A+B}2\right)}{2\cos\frac{A+B}2\left(\cos\frac{A+B}2+i\sin\frac{A+B}2\right)}$$

$$=\frac{\cos\frac{A-B}2}{\cos\frac{A+B}2}$$

Comment: If you could finish i would be really thankfull, and i cant figure out what you did on the second step. today i learned i'm really bad at math

Comment: @vordep, please find the edited version

Comment: once again thank you, but the second step i couldnt figure what you did was from this ${1+\{\cos(A+B)+i\sin(A+B)\}}$ to ${2\cos^2\frac{A+B}2+i2\sin\frac{A+B}2\cos\frac{A+B}2}$

Comment: @vordep, as $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1,\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$

Answer (score 9):

We have $$\frac{z-w}{1-zw}=\frac{(z-w)(1-\overline{zw})}{(1-zw)(1-\overline{zw})}$$
Note that $(1-zw)(1-\overline{zw})=1-(zw+\overline{zw})+|zw|^2$ is real, so we need only consider the numerator (as Berci hinted).

We calculate $(z-w)(1-\overline{zw})=z-w-|z|^2\overline{w}+|w|^2\overline{z}=(z+\overline{z})-(w+\overline{w})$, which is real.

Comment: My friend sent me the wrong question, but the principle its the same right?

Comment: The updated version is identical, with $w$ replaced by $-w$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For complex numbers $a,b$ we have $a/b\in\Bbb R\iff a\bar b\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

We have $|\zeta|=1 \Leftrightarrow \bar{\zeta}=\frac{1}{\zeta}$.

$|z|=|w|=1 \Leftrightarrow \bar{z}=\frac{1}{z} \text{and } \bar{w}=\frac{1}{w} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\bar{z}+\bar{w}}{1+\bar{z}\bar{w}}=\frac{\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{w}}{1+\frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{w}} \Leftrightarrow \overline{ \left(\frac{z+w}{1+zw}\right)}=\frac{z+w}{1+zw} \Leftrightarrow \frac{z+w}{1+zw} \in \mathbb R$

Comment: $1+z\cdot w$ is not necessarily real

Comment: I fixed it ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: why did you change  ${{z+w} \over {1+zw}} $  to $ \frac{\bar{z}+\bar{w}}{1+\bar{z}\bar{w}}$, i dont think its the same.

Comment: It is not, it's its conjugate.

Answer (score 2):

Draw vectors on the complex plane from the origin to a point on the unit circle. Notice that the argument of the sum of two such vectors is the average of the arguments of the two vectors (observe that the latter is defined only modulo a multiple of $\pi$). This follows from the properties of a rhombus (=parallelogram with equal sides).

Let $\arg z=\alpha$ and $\arg w=\beta$. By the above observation 
$\arg(z+w)=(\alpha+\beta)/2\pmod\pi$. It is well known that $\arg zw=\alpha+\beta$. As $\arg1=0$ another application of the above observation gives that 
$\arg(1+zw)=(\alpha+\beta)/2\pmod \pi$.

So $z+w$ and $1+zw$ share the same argument modulo an integer multiple of $\pi$. This means that the argument of their ratio is a multiple of $\pi$, and hence the ratio itself is real.

Comment: So what i learned from this is that     $arg (z +w)= \frac {a+b} {2} $

,$arg (1 + zw)= \frac {0+a+b} {2} $
then,

$ \frac {z+w}{1+zw}$ =$\frac{\frac {a+b}{2}}{\frac{0+a+b}{2}}$

this is the ratio you were talking about

Comment: @vordep: In the last step: the argument of a ratio is the **difference** of the arguments (analogously to the argument of a product being the sum of the arguments). Also, it is important that the pairs, $z$ and $w$, as well as $1$ and $zw$ have the same absolute values. Otherwise the rule: "argument of a sum is the average of arguments" does not hold. The point here was the geometric viewpoint.

Comment: oh yeah, thats what i meant, thanks

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $z \bar z=|z|^2=1$ and similarly for $w,$

$$\frac{z+w}{1+zw}=\frac{\frac1{\bar z}+\frac1{\bar w}}{1+\frac1{\bar z}\frac1{\bar w}}=\frac{\bar w+\bar z}{1+\bar w\bar z}$$

$$\text{Using  }\frac ab=\frac cd=\frac{a+c}{b+d},$$

$$\frac{z+w}{1+zw}=\frac{\bar w+\bar z}{1+\bar w\bar z}=\frac{z+w+\bar w+\bar z}{1+zw+1+\bar w\bar z}=\frac{(z+\bar z)+(w+\bar w)}{2+(zw+\overline{wz})}$$ as $\bar z\cdot \bar w=\overline{z\cdot w}$

Observe that each pair within parentheses is real