# Operations with complex numbers to give real numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

If:

1. $|z|=|w|=1$
2. $1 + zw \neq 0$

Then $\dfrac{z+w}{1+zw}$ is real.  How can prove that.

Comment: One thing, if you want to see whether $\frac{a}{b}$ is real (or purely imaginary) is to multiply with $\frac{\overline{b}}{\overline{b}}$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427663/prove-if-z-w-1-and-1zw-neq-0-then-zw-over-1zw-is-a-real?rq=1 .

Comment: Thanks. This is a repeated question. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the complex conjugate then multiply top and bottom by $zw$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=e^{ia}$ and $w=e^{ib}$ for some $a,b \in [0,2\pi)$. This takes care of condition 1. Then $1+zw \neq 0$ means $1+e^{i(a+b)} \neq 0$, which is the same as saying $a+b$ is not an odd multiple of $\pi$.

Now consider
\begin{align*}
 \dfrac{z+w}{1+zw} & = \frac{e^{ia}+e^{ib}}{1+e^{i(a+b)}}
\end{align*}
Rationalize the denominator and see what happens.